# returned variable is of type object promise and unable to render

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

By default the object is returned by promise and it is my understand that I need to have an `await` or a `then` to initialize a map the res to another locally created object.

axios call

```
async getAllCourses() {
    try {
        const res = await request.get<ResponseData>("/v1/courses");

        return res.data

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
},
```

This works

```
let results: Course[];

let courses = api.getAllCourses().then((res: ResponseData) => {

    results = res.data

    return results
})
```

This however does not:

```
let courses = await api.getAllCourses().then((res: ResponseData) => {

    let c: Course[];
    c = res.data

    return c
})
```

---

```
export default interface ResponseData {
    data: any;
}
```

---- data from server----

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ObjectId": "649419c9e26f71024a0d5901",
            "id": "",
            "title": "Algorithms",
            "description": "An awesome GO course",
            "lessons": "5",
            "duration": "7 hours",
            "course_details": {
                "title": "",
                "instructor": "Mike",
                "introduction": "",
                "learn": "Lets do this",
                "topics": "foo, bar, yes",
                "prerequisites": "basic golang skills",
                "goal": "To Make you Amazing",
                "additionalDetails": "",
                "highLevelOverview": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "ObjectId": "64953ac1bf06bfdd7936cad8",
            "id": "",
            "title": "Python Algorithms",
            "description": "An awesome Python course",
            "lessons": "5",
            "duration": "7 hours",
            "course_details": {
                "title": "",
                "instructor": "Mike",
                "introduction": "",
                "learn": "Lets do this",
                "topics": "foo, bar",
                "prerequisites": "basic",
                "goal": "It will Make you Amazing at Python",
                "additionalDetails": "",
                "highLevelOverview": ""
            }
        },
        }
    ],
    "metadata": "none"
}
```

---

I would like to keep the logic of mapping the response to a ts object within the method.

What is the correct way to do this?

------ update 1 ---

I now have

```
export default interface ResponseData<T = any> {
    data: T;
}
```

axios call

```
export const api = {

    async getAllCourses(): Promise<Course[]> {

        const res = await request.get<ResponseData<Course[]>>("/v1/courses");

        return res.data.data

    },

}
```

component

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { api } from "../lib/api";

import Course from "../components/courses/Course.vue";
import Filter from "../components/courses/Filter.vue";
import ResponseData from "../lib/models/ResponseData";

const courses = await api.getAllCourses()

</script>
```

No error and nothing renders :(

I did see however the array in the axios call when I `console.log(res.data)`

[image]

---- update 2 -----

I kinda have it working but sometimes it doesn't render. I refresh it several times and then sometimes it renders.

```
let courses = api.getAllCourses().then((res: Course[]) => {

    results = res

    return results
})
```

axios

```
async getAllCourses(): Promise<Course[]> {
    const res = await request.get<Course[]>("/v1/courses");

    console.log(res.data)

    return res.data

},
```

--

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 h-4 md:w-4/5 p-4">
    <div class="md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-1 col-gap-2 md:col-gap-8 md:row-gap-10" v-for='(course, index) in results'>
        <Course :key="index" :course="course"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, since in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gVwE4GdoF4oG8BQUoB2AhgLYQBcUKwSAlgQOYDcOAvizqJFAEoQpg4BNABEiwIlEy58AE3FFK8ZGgDaAXRbscOAMZDqUImFpTseKAwjAAggBs7y1P0pZWRlFAAUASikA+KAAFJDgSWjQAHj4BAwgxCX8AGjYOfWFgKAAza10ACyc0T0wiFBACXW8-dECZKDtrKH0VfjMiAHciWkzjWgA6K1sHQv5fPuA8iAIvLyQXXn5BYXiFatqLfAbM3SVEZw0WfHxKzDmUPvkJDiOoOeBkAibDqFYfLRYgA) `courses` is `Course[]`

Comment: `await` resolves the promise, you don't need `then`.
Also, the function you call this in should be async.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: @wonderflame not sure either. I added more to the post. Thank you for posting

Comment: Nothing renders because you are using top-level await in the script block of a Vue component. The component will not have that value initially (unless using Suspense, maybe), and will not rerender when it does. Rather use a ref and use `.then()` to set its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your server wraps return data into an object with a `data` property, the type you set on `request.get()` should be `Course[]`:

```
const res = await request.get<Course[]>("/v1/courses");
```

This will set `res` to be of type `AxiosResponse<Course[]>`, where `AxiosResponse` is [defined as](https://github.com/whylisa/typescript/blob/master/axios.ts#L47-L54):

```
export interface AxiosResponse<T = any> {
    data: T
    status: number
    statusText: string
    headers: any
    configL: AxiosRequestConfig
    request: any
}
```

With this, your `getAllCourses()` will return `Promise<Course[]>`. You can then use it without any additional unwrapping:

```
const courses = await api.getAllCourses()
```

---

If your server does actually wrap its response in an additional object with a `data` property and you cannot change that, you should make your `ResponseData` type generic, similar to the `AxiosResponse`:

```
export default interface ResponseData<T = any> {
    data: T;
}
```

and set and unwrap it in your `getAllCourses()` accordingly:

```
async getAllCourses(): Promise<Course[]> {
  try{
    const res = await request.get<ResponseData<Course[]>>("/v1/courses");
    return res.data.data // <---- first data from AxiosResponse, second from your server
  ...
```

This would again return `Promise<Course[]>` and you can use it as above.

---

Here is a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) which replicates what you described.

Comment: I added update 1. Thank you very much for posting but sadly it did not work.

Comment: Can you please add the data returned by the server?

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is. I see the array in the axio call when I console.log. `console.log(res.data)`. I added a screenshot

Comment: Ah, looking at the data, the axios bindings are correct now. You are running into a different problem now. As @DarrylNoakes pointed out, using `await` inside script setup turns your component into an [async component](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html). You'll either have to handle it accordingly, or use `.then()` instead: `const courses = ref([]); api.getAllCourses().then(c => courses.value = c)`

Comment: I made a update 2. This is very strange

Comment: That did it. There are other issues but this solved it .... Thank you

Comment: I was wrong.. It is still not mapping the response to my TS model.

Comment: Check the updated answer, I have added link to a playground which replicates the setup as you described it. Please compare it with your component, maybe it helps you figuring out what is not working. Let me know if there is something else I can do.

Comment: Thank you for the updated post. It appears I have the same as you which is what confuses me more. This is my repo https://github.com/drewjocham/fullstack-guru/tree/courses_view/view/src. I am still trying different things out and seeing what sticks.

Comment: The github link gives me a 404. Is the repo public?

Comment: Ahh sorry. I just changed it.

Comment: In `api.getAllCourses()`, it says `request.get<Course[]>(...)` in [this line](https://github.com/drewjocham/fullstack-guru/blob/c945e884b78c246b3a4f9d90fecddc95a43b1f89/view/src/lib/api.ts#L17), but according to the image and what you said before, it should be `request.get<{data: Course[], metadata: 'none'}>(...)`, and then `return res.data.data` instead of just `res.data` in [this line](https://github.com/drewjocham/fullstack-guru/blob/c945e884b78c246b3a4f9d90fecddc95a43b1f89/view/src/lib/api.ts#L21). Does that make sense? I have updated the playground to make it more apparent.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I just added a bounty. I cannot award it to you for 24 hours. Vielen Dank! Ich hoffe du hattest einen Guten start in der Woche ;)

Comment: Oh, that's so nice, thank you! Macht meine Woche gleich besser :) Schöne Grüße aus dem angenehm kühlen Leipzig. Alles Gute!